# Parent.Grid + Child.Grid => Shared ColumnDefinitions

Tags: c#, wpf, grid

I want to share a parent column definition with a child grid.

I have a parent grid like:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <controls:GridEntry />
  <controls:GridEntry />
  <controls:GridEntry />
</Grid>
```

and a child that is a UserControl (controls:GridEntry) with following content:

```
<Grid>
  <Label x:Name="caption" />
  <TextBox x:Name="value" />
  <Button x:Name="button" />
</Grid>
```

My current idea is to find the parent grid from the child and set the constraints (if possible as binding, otherwise copy. When copying I have to catch all resize operations manually).

Is there an easy way to transfer the ColumnDefinitions of the parent grid to the child grid (preferably via XAML)?

Comment: Why don't you just use Grid.RowDefinitions?

Comment: As you have set neither `Grid.Column` nor `Grid.Row`, all elements will be overlapped. It is hard to understand what kind of placement you are expecting from the code.

Comment: The way to share column widths is to use the attribute setting `Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True"` on the outer-panel (whatever its type) and then to use the`Grid.SharedSizeGroup` attribute on the column definitions you want  shared.   This is straight from the MS documentation:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.grid.issharedsizescope?view=windowsdesktop-7.0